# Creating / Using a stored procedure with a Laravel migration

Tags: mysql, laravel, stored-procedures, eloquent, laravel-migrations

This one is a little squirrely!

I have built a stored procedure that works fine. However, when I put it into a Laravel (eloquent) migration, the migration builds the stored procedure but when it is called it gives me an error 1292 (Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value). From mysql workbench, I then right click on the stored procedure built by the migration, copy the create statement, delete the stored procedure and rebuild it from its own create statement.... AND..... EVERYTHING WORKS FINE!

I am open to any and all guesses. I obviously want this stored procedure to be part of my migrations and not have it be something that needs to be built manually. Thanks in advance:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE sp_cancelTasksOnApplicationCancel(IN loanAppId INT(20))

BEGIN

            SELECT loanAppId;

            #SET @taskids := 0;

            update tasks set task_status = 26, task_status_note = 'Application Cancelled or Denied' 

where loan_app_id = loanAppId AND task_status IN (22, 23, 24) AND ( SELECT @taskids := CONCAT_WS(',', id, @taskids) );        

#SELECT @taskids;

SET @cleanids = SUBSTRING(@taskids, 1, CHAR_LENGTH(@taskids) -1);

#SELECT @cleanids;

            SET @pos = 0;

            SET @len = 0;

            WHILE LOCATE(',', @cleanids, @pos+1) > 0 DO

                            SET @len = LOCATE(',', @cleanids,@pos+1) - @pos;

                            SET @id = SUBSTRING(@cleanids, @pos, @len);

                                            #select (@id);

                                            IF (@id <> 0) THEN

                                            insert into status_historys 

                                                            (loan_app_id, `type`, type_recid, type_keyfield,type_status_field, type_status_date_field, type_status_note_field, type_status_userid_field, `status`, status_date, status_note, status_userid, created_at, updated_at) 

            values(loanAppId, 'tasks', @id, 'id', 'task status', 'tasks status datetime', 'tasks status note', 'tasks status userid', 26, now(), 'Application Cancelled or Denied', 1, now(), now()); 

                                            END IF;

                            SET @pos = LOCATE(',', @taskids, @pos+@len) + 1;

            END WHILE;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

##############  UPDATE

The problem lies in the following two lines. Even from the command line it gives a warning about the incorrect double value.

```
SET @taskids := '0';

update tasks set task_status = 22, task_status_note = 'Just Testing' 
where loan_app_id = loanAppId AND task_status IN (22, 23, 24) AND ( SELECT 
@taskids := CONCAT_WS(',', cast(id as char), @taskids) );
```

Comment: Please add your migration code from laravel concerning this stored procedure.

Comment: I found a syntax mistake in  `type` and `status column

Comment: type and status are mysql keywords. They need to be protected with backticks if you use them as column names. I will repeat. This stored procedure runs fine with the exception of when it is loaded via a laravel migration. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

OK - The main problem was the select keyword in the update where clause. I believe it kept re-declaring the @taskids user variable and mysql gave warnings if the stored procedure was built from the workbench, but failed if the stored procedure was built by a migration.

So the correct code was

```
#snip#
#Note string '0' rather than 0
SET @taskids := '0';

#note casting of id and removing the select keyword before the first @taskids
update tasks set task_status = 22, task_status_note = 'Just Testing' 
where loan_app_id = loanAppId AND task_status IN (22, 23, 24) AND (  
@taskids := CONCAT_WS(',', cast(id as char), @taskids) );

#snip#
```